# COUNT() AND GROUP BY in BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tried to use UNNEST in BigQuery but the output looks like this

```
------------------------------------------
|Row |    Name         |   user_id       ｜
------------------------------------------
| 1  |    STAY         |      1          ｜
-    -------------------
|    |LOVE YOURSELF    |                 ｜
-    -------------------
|    |  GREEN BOOK     |                 ｜
-    -------------------
|    |CRAZY IN LOVE    |                 ｜
------------------------------------------
```

And my query is :

```
select user_id,
       array(select json_extract_scalar(x, '$.Name') from 
       unnest(json_extract_array(json_col, '$.info.music') x) NAME
from data
```

I expected the table to be as following because I wanted to count the number of users who listen to each song. Does anyone have any suggestions? Could I actually count using the above table?

```
------------------------------------------
|Row |    Name         |   user_id       ｜
------------------------------------------
| 1  |    STAY         |      1          ｜
------------------------------------------
| 2  |LOVE YOURSELF    |      1          ｜
------------------------------------------
| 3  |  GREEN BOOK     |      1          ｜
------------------------------------------
| 4  |CRAZY IN LOVE    |      1          ｜
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: select user_id,
       array(select json_extract_scalar(x, '$.Name') from 
       unnest(json_extract_array(json_col, '$.info.music') x) NAME
from data

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select name, user_id from (
  select user_id,
    array(select json_extract_scalar(x, '$.Name') from 
    unnest(json_extract_array(json_col, '$.info.music')) x) NAME
  from data
) t, t.name name
```

with output

[image]